# In the process of Diffusion Limited Aggregation (DLA), why do the particles prefer to form something which has the shape of a tree?

Tags: diffusion, brownian-motion, randomness

In the process of Diffusion Limited Aggregation (DLA), why do the particles prefer to form something which has the shape of a tree instead of just a front line?

[image]

Comment: Random aggregation causes branches to spontaneously form that then occlude the nearby space. It's an entirely kinetic process which is why you don't get a linear growth front.